# Astro: Cannot Run Theme Template Project - Parse failure: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, astrojs

I have downloaded a project from github and cannot run it at all.

Node Version: v20.5.0
NPM Version: 9.8.0

I've tried googling and debugging but I have no idea what's wrong. Lost countless ideas and need help.

Could someone help me out please?

Have cloned the entire project: [https://github.com/mhyfritz/astro-landing-page][github link]

Run the commands:

```
npm install

npm run dev
```

Visiting http://localhost:3000/

I receive the following error message on the webpage:

```
Error An error occurred. Parse failure: Unexpected token (81:70) At file: /node_modules/@astrojs/image/dist/lib/get-image.js Contents of line 81:   const isDev = (_b = (Object.assign(import.meta.env,{_:process.env._,-:process.env.-,SSR:true,}))) == null ? void 0 : _b.DEV;
```

I've tried so many different things but cannot figure out why this isn't working.

Could you please help me and explain what was going wrong so I don't run into this issue again.

Thank you so much

Comment: Not sure if it's causing the problem, but you would wanna use the [recommended](https://nodejs.org/en) version of Node.js.

Comment: @YoussoufOumar Still getting the same errors on Node 18 and 20 etc.